# How to specify `pip.conf` to allow packages download from aritifactory?

Tags: python, pip, artifactory, pypi

i have a couple of packages which I need to install from artifactory and a couple of them need to be downloaded from the public pypi.org, my `pip.conf` file looks like this:

```
[global]
index-url = https://xx/artifactory/xxx/simple

extra-index-url = https://xxx/artifactory/xxx/simple (# this is a mirror of pypi)
```

Theoretically this should work, because anything that's not in the first url, it'll check the mirror of public pypi and download from there, but when i try to download packages in the `requirements.txt` file, it couldn't find the package `behave`

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement behave==xxx(from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for behave==xxx
```

Am i missing anything here?=

Comment: what is your python version? Does it install without artifactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do refer to this [screencast](https://jfrog.com/screencast/setting-up-pypi-repository-in-minutes-with-jfrog-artifactory/) to set up pip with Artifactory. Moreover, the issue seems to be related to the index-url which should be as below,

```
[global]
index-url = https://myart.jfrog.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual-repo/simple
```